# Json object into array list with RetroFit Android

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit

I'm trying to get this data from a rest API and show on Recycler view. I try to convert my JSON Object into an ArrayList, but I don't have success. My code returns this: []
Currently, I'm using Retrofit with POJO classes.

[image: My JSON]

```
//Header

ArrayList<Model> carsModels=new ArrayList<>();
private Adapter carsAdapter;


Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://example.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestInteface requestInteface = retrofit.create(RequestInteface.class);
    Call<Model> call = requestInteface.getInteressJson();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                carsModels = new ArrayList<>(response.body().getModelList()); 
                carsAdapter = new Adapter(home.this, carsModels);
                cars_recyclerview.setAdapter(carsAdapter);
                Toast.makeText(home.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
```

Model Class:

```
public class Model {
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("audience_size")
@Expose
private String audience_size;
@SerializedName("topic")
@Expose
private String topic;
@SerializedName("path")
@Expose
private String path;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;

private List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();


//Getter and setter
```

**Request interface:**

```
interface RequestInteface {
@GET("search.json")
Call<Model> getInteressJson();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parse "data" first, inside "data" contain `List<Model>` Create class `InteressResponse`

```
public class InteressResponse {
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Model> modelList;

//Getter and setter
}
```

```
interface RequestInteface {
@GET("search.json")
Call<InteressResponse> getInteressJson();
}
```

```
public void onResponse(Call<InteressResponse> call, Response<InteressResponse> response) {
      if(response.isSuccessful()){
          carsModels = new ArrayList<>(response.body().getModelList()); 
          carsAdapter = new Adapter(home.this, carsModels);
          cars_recyclerview.setAdapter(carsAdapter);
          Toast.makeText(home.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
}
```

Remove `private List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();` inside class `Model`

Comment: return this error: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference